# How to move my image to the right of my 'contact us' form?

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm currently creating a website as part of an assignment, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get my image to display correctly on my 'contact us' page.

I want it to display to the right of the 'first name, last name, and email field' but currently it's just sitting below and creating a large space between the next part of the form. [click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy5MH.png)

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML/CSS here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the user above mentioned, you can use flex to fix it.

Wrap both the image and the form into divs (separated from each other) and also the whole things into another parent div
ex.:

```html
<div class="parent">
<!-- here write the form div -->

  <div class="form-whatever">
    <form> ... </form>
 </div>


<!-- here write the image div -->

  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="x" >
  </div>

</div>
```

now in the css simply do this:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Now this way it should work properly.

Comment: Thanks so much! that has worked :D

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the code, looks like the form and image are in different divs and not siblings. you need to do something like this:

```
<div>
   <form>float left</form>
   <image>float right</image>
</div>
```

or use flex on the parent div.

A copy of your source code will be helpful